# Heroku CI Unable to initialize CI build environment,

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-ci

I'm setting up Heroku CI for my app and I'm getting the following error: Could not create test run. Unable to initialize CI build environment, please try again.

Problem is I have no idea why. I have my app.json set up like so:

```
{
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "scripts": {
        "test-setup": "python manage.py flush --noinput && python manage.py migrate --settings=app.settings.heroku",
        "test": "python manage.py heroku --settings=app.settings.heroku"
      },
      "addons": [
          "heroku-postgresql:in-dyno",
          "heroku-redis:in-dyno"
      ],
      "buildpacks": [
        {
            "url": "https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: There should be some more detailed output on the error in the heroku pipeline. see if you can find anything else. For me, it was that I had forgotten to define my environment variables for the testing environment. Be sure to do that inside of the testing settings tab of the pipeline